# How much time do I have before killing someone else to do a combo?

Tags: unreal-tournament-4

In the new Unreal Tournament, when I kill 2-3 guys in a row in a few seconds, I get a double/triple/multikill combo. 
I wonder how much time I have before killing someone else after I kill someone to do a combo. 
I know that it's not forever as sometimes people are scrambled across the map and it doesn't count it as a kill when I kill them.

Comment: Not sure with the new game, but it is normally about 4-5 seconds between kills.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's 3 seconds.

Defined in source file [UTGameState.cpp](https://github.com/EpicGames/UnrealTournament/blob/1bdea689c052606cfad084a517e4bb3d1b6b29ea/UnrealTournament/Source/UnrealTournament/Private/UTGameState.cpp) (on github, MultiKillDelay = 3.0f;). Calculated in [UTPlayerState.cpp](https://github.com/EpicGames/UnrealTournament/blob/75d2780293c99ca37d0e1dac045af37be17b17a6/UnrealTournament/Source/UnrealTournament/Private/UTPlayerState.cpp)

Take note that in order to view those files on github, you must be logged in on github and [have linked](http://help.epicgames.com/customer/en/portal/articles/2293871-how-do-i-link-my-unreal-engine-account-with-my-github-account-?b_id=9727) your github account on Epic Games website.

Comment: It might be a good idea to include the link the the github file in your answer.

Comment: I wanted to, but they aren't publicly visible :) I explained in answer.

Comment: Brilliant answer, thanks for digging in the source code, I had access to repo but I didn't really check it as I'm not familiar with codebase.